# Total sum per day in a graph

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Let me excuse me for not finding the answer to my question. I've got no clue on what to look for.

I'm keeping a logbook with times. It contains information with how long I have worked. I need to make a graph that will show the amount of work I've done in total.

For example on day 1 I worked 1 hour and on day 2 I have worked 2 hours.
I fill the date in column A and the labour in column B. In my graph I need to see that I have worked 1 hour total on day 1, and I have worked 3 hours total on day 2 (basically I need to sum everything up)

I've tried fixing this myself by making a sum of the column in a new column, but this is just way too much work to do for the amount of rows I need.
I've did this for every cell in column E through row 14, until I decided to ask help from stack overflow

[image]

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: This question is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), you might find more help on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E1:

```
=SOM($D1:D1)
```

Auto Drag fill down.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me alot of time :)